# When I combine files with cmd command copy why would there be an extra space at the end of the new file and how can I remove it

Tags: powershell, batch-file, cmd

When I combine files with cmd command `copy` why would there be an extra space at the end of the new file and how to remove it.

I tried to combine files with cmd and powershell using the command `copy`.

cmd command:

```
copy /y C:\x1.txt + C:\x2.txt C:\x3.txt
```

powershell command:

```
cmd /c copy /y C:\x1.txt + C:\x2.txt C:\x3.txt
```

I got my `x3.txt` file but there's an extra space at the end of `x3.txt`
Why is that happening and how can I remove that extra space using cmd or powershell?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure that the extra character is a <kbd>Space</kbd> - I suspect it's actually a <kbd>Ctrl-Z</kbd>

```
copy /y C:\x1.txt + C:\x2.txt C:\x3.txt /B
```

should solve the problem - output in `/B` (binary) mode.

<kbd>Ctrl-Z</kbd> traditionally marks end-of-text-file